# Irreducible Representations: Howard Georgi's book

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, matrix-elements

I am currently studying the book *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* by Howard Georgi (2nd edition) and I couldn't understand this part:

> A representation is completely reducible if it is equivalent to a representation whose matrix elements have the following form:
> $$\begin{bmatrix}D_1(g) & 0 & 0\ ... \\0&D_2(g) &0\ ... \\ ...\ & ...\ & ... \end{bmatrix}$$
> where $D_j(g)$ is irreducible for all $j$. This is called block diagonal form.

Notation: $g$ refers to an element of a group $G$ and $D$ is a representation.

What I don't quite get is: Those diagonal elements are just *numbers* aren't they? Then what's with calling them irreducible representations? Going further, the author says:

> A representation in block diagonal form is said to be the direct sum
> of  the subrepresentations, $D_j$s

I am a beginner so excuse me if this is trivial. Why exactly did he say that those matrix elements are representations themselves? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements on the diagonal $D_j(g)$, are not just numbers. They are in general matrices. That is why it is called *block* diagonal. As a very simple example, take SU(2): the tensor product of two SU(2) matrices, each being in the two-dimensional representation, would give you a four-dimensional matrix. Using the appropriate transformation of this matrix, one can reduce it to a block diagonal form with a three-dimensional matrix and a one-dimensional element sitting on the diagonal. The three-dimensional matrix represents the adjoint representation of SU(2) and the one-dimensional element is the singlet representation. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for answering. A follow up question: Will we still call it completely reducible if we can write it as above but the matrices $D_i$ are not irreducible? Is it even possible that they are still reducible?

Comment: @Sarthak  :  See some details of this flippiefanus' example in my answer  here [What is the symmetry of the pion triplet (π−,π0,π+)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420080/what-is-the-symmetry-of-the-pion-triplet-pi-pi0-pi)  $\color{blue}{\textbf{Example A :}}$.

Comment: @Sarthak: Not sure I understand your question. A fully reducible case implies the block diagonal form. There are cases where it is not possible to reduce the matrix to the block diagonal form - some off-diagonal block remain non-zero. In that case, it is not fully reducible. If the matrix is fully reducible, the resulting representations obtained from the blocks on the diagonal are said to be irreducible.